# Flutter/Flame game homepage or homeview inconsistency

Tags: flutter, flame

I have a home-view and in this homeview I have placed my homepage pic, start and settings buttons.

When I run my game in the first opening, homepage pic is shown smaller and the buttons are not shown.

But if i click on restart in the emulator everything looks normal and well-sized. In a real android device homepage pic always smaller and the buttons are not shown.

```
Util flameUtil = Util();
await flameUtil.fullScreen();
await flameUtil.setLandscapeLeftOnly();
```

**I want to prefer landscape left only.**

```
void resize(Size size) {
screenSize = size;
tileSize = screenSize.width / 9;}
```

this is my resize method.

```
titleRect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 
0, 
game.tileSize*10, 
game.tileSize*5);

titleSprite = Sprite('uipics/homepage.png');
```

my homepage pic

```
rect = Rect.fromLTWH(game.tileSize*5, 
(game.screenSize.height) - (game.tileSize*1.5), 
game.tileSize*0.9, 
game.tileSize*0.8);


sprite = Sprite('uipics/playbutton.png');
```

my start(play) button.

```
rect = Rect.fromLTWH(game.tileSize*7.2, 
game.screenSize.height - (game.tileSize *1.5), 
game.tileSize*0.9, 
game.tileSize*0.8);
```

my settings button.

as I mentioned, if i click on restart in my IDE(vsc) everthing is automatically fixed and I can play my game without any problem. but in the first running and in an android device it is problematic. I have tried changing the sizes and the positions but it never worked successfully. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Where in your code are you calling `await flameUtil.fullScreen();`?

Comment: void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  
  TheGame game = TheGame(storage);
 
  runApp(game.widget);
 
  Util flameUtil = Util();
  await flameUtil.fullScreen();
  await flameUtil.setLandscapeLeftOnly();   in main.dart file like that

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the `await flameUtil.fullScreen();` and `setLandscapeLeftOnly();` before you do `runApp`, something like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await Flame.util.fullScreen(); 
  await Flame.util.setLandscapeLeftOnly();
  TheGame game = TheGame(storage); 
  runApp(game.widget);
}
```

Comment: void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Util flameUtil = Util();
  await flameUtil.fullScreen();
  await flameUtil.setLandscapeLeftOnly();
  TheGame game = TheGame(storage);
  runApp(game.widget); . in main.dart I changed the code as you suggested but it did not make any difference.I can change the size of my homepage pic. then it suits the screen however my buttons aren't shown. when I change their position randomly I see them but when the second time I start the game it is all broken again.

Comment: Maybe you could try the NineTileBox? Like we do here:
https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/tree/master/doc/examples/nine_tile_box

Comment: NineTileBox did not work as well. but I have fixed it by putting Flame.images.loadAll before runApp. Now when I run my game it works normally. but now I have faced with another problem. release apk giving the same error. homapage is small and buttons are not seen. on the other hand. app.apk, the apk created when I run my game works perfectly. Why does it make a difference. How can I fix my release apk? Do you know why two apks work differently? Thank you very much